# I want to be able to input variable in the trigger

Tags: texstudio

I want to write a macros in TeXstudio, in this way for example :

```
normofuequal1
so the result :
||u||=1
normofyequal10.89
so the result :

    ||y||=10.89
```

in other words I want to be able to input variable in the trigger.
Thank you
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. At the moment, it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. For instance, what is `normofuequal`? What does "trigger" mean in the present context? Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico, I want trigger for my example to be  like : normof(first variable)equal(second variable), and macros be : \|first variable\|=second variable

Comment: @Mico in TeXstudio when you write trigger as in photo, for example frame the editor call the micros

Comment: @Rabah - I don't use TeXstudio myself. Maybe that explains why I'm not familiar with a term such as "trigger" -- at least not in the present context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on the TexStudio GitHub page, specifically at the following link:
https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/wiki/Scripts#generate-environment-after-typing-trigger-code

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

Note that the default "connector symbol" used by `\normof` is `=`. If you want a different symbol, you must specify it in the optional first argument.

Note that I don't use TeXstudio and am therefore not familiar with the usage of the term "trigger" -- at least not in this context.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\newcommand\normof[3][=]{\norm{#2}#1#3}

\begin{document}
$\normof{u}{1} \qquad \normof{y}{10.89} \qquad \normof[<]{a}{\varepsilon}$
\end{document}
```